# Intent send crashes

Tags: java, android, android-intent, send, whatsapp

I try to send text message with whatsapp but this code fails every time.

```
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, txtMessage.getText().toString());
            startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Comment: Why does it fail? And how?

Comment: what is the crash log?. Post here

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution  for send the message to whatsapp from our application

```
public void onClickWhatsApp() {

    PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
    try {

        Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        waIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String text = "YOUR TEXT HERE";

        PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        //Check if package exists or not. If not then code 
        //in catch block will be called
        waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

        waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));

   } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
   }  

}
```

Also see http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012